# How to disassemble this hinge?

Tags: repair, shed, hinges

I have a shed of which the doors are not closing correctly anymore because the doors are hanging. I would like to disassemble the hinges in order to correct this problem, however I do not know how to diassemble the hinges. Therefore, does anyone know these hinges or can tell me how to open them? Both ends of the hinges, seem to be either screwed into the wood of the door, or into the wood of the frame? Also, sorry for the atrocious paint job over the hinges, this was not me :D.

[image: Hinge from the front]
[image: Hinge from the top]
[image: Hinge from the bottom]

Comment: Will need to remove all the paint on top and bottom.  Hopefully can then find pin that you can pry up or punch up with a drift pin(nail/screw/ piece of steel rod).

Comment: You could start by giving the protrusion at the bottom a whack with a hammer. I don't see a screwhead or hexagonal nut at the bottom, so it's most likely a smooth pen with the head resting on top. If it doesn't immediately give way, proceed with paint removal to uncover more details.

Comment: While the two comments above make a lot of sense, it might be easier to simply remove the nuts holding the hinge to the door. (Assuming the bolts go through and there are nuts on the other side.)

Comment: Thanks for your good inputs! I could diassemble the hinge by driving the pin out with a hammer from below just as @MiG suggested. If anyone wants to post an according answer, I would be happy to confirm it.

Comment: Glad to hear! I'll transfer it to an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start by giving the protrusion at the bottom a whack with a hammer. I don't see a screwhead or hexagonal nut at the bottom, so it's most likely a smooth pin with the head resting on top.

If it doesn't immediately give way, proceed with paint removal to uncover more details.